# JButton won't change label and add new one

Tags: java, swing, button

Ok so this is supposed to be a simple program to remove one label and add another but when I click the button nothing happens. I am fairly new to anything swing or J related so please be as explanatory as possible.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    class JDisappearingFriends{
        public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(100, 100);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("Hello");
        frame1.add(label1);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();

        JButton btnChangeFriends = new JButton("Change Friends");
        btnChangeFriends.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame1.remove(label1);
                label2.setText("Goodbye");
                frame1.add(label2);
        }
        });


        frame1.getContentPane().add(btnChangeFriends, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just change the text on the label:

```
label1.setText(...);
```

When you add/remove components from the GUI you need to invoke the layout manager. The basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```